# NumberFormatException for input String - Java

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I'm trying to round the cents of a value.
The rounding seems to work, but there's an exception:

```
double amount = 289.42;
String f= String.format("%.1f", amount);
  
System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("##0.00").format(Double.valueOf(f)));
```

This is the error: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "289,4"`

Comment: You have a default locale that uses a comma `,` as decimal separator, so `String.format` used that when creating the string, but `Double.valueOf` **always** uses `.` as the decimal separator. Either you need to use `String.format(Locale, String, Object...)` with a `Locale` that use a `.` as the decimal separator, or you need to use a decimal format to parse the string `f`.

Comment: Thank you. Solved!

     `String f = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH,"%.1f", amount);
     System.out.println( new DecimalFormat("##0.00").format(Double.valueOf(f)));`

Answer (score 0):

Your question posits an impossibility.

Here's the thing: You **cannot** represent currency amounts with `double`. At all. Thus, 'how do I render these cents-in-a-double appropriately' isn't a sensible concept in the first place. Because cents cannot be stored in a double.

The problem lies in what `double` *are*, fundamentally. `double` is a numeric storage system that is defined to consist of exactly 64 bits. That's a problem right there: It's a mathematical fact that 64 bits can store at most 2^64 unique things, because, well, math. Think about it.

The problem is, There are in fact an *infinite* amount of numbers between 0 and 1, let alone between -infinity and +infinity which `double` would appear to represent. So, how do you square that circle? How does one represent one specific value chosen from an infinite amount of infinities, with only 64 bits?

The answer is simple. **You don't**.

doubles do **not** in fact store arbitrary values at all. **And that is why you cannot use them to store currencies**. Instead, take the number line and mark off slightly less than 2^64 specific values on it. We'll call these 'the blessed numbers'. A `double` can only store blessed numbers. They can't store anything else. In addition, any math you do to doubles is silently rounded to the nearest blessed value as doubles can't store anything else. So, 0.1 + 0.1? Not actually 0.2. Instead, 0.1 isn't even blessed, so that's really round-to-blessed(0.1) + round-to-blessed(0.1), so actually that's 0.0999999999975 + 0.0999999999975 = 0.2000000000018 or whatever. The blessed numbers are distributed unequally - there are a ton of blessed numbers in the 0-1 range, and as you move away from the 0, the distance between 2 blessed numbers grows larger and larger. Their distribution makes sense, but, computers count in binary, so they fall on neat boundaries *in binary*, not in decimal (0.1 looks neat in decimal. It's similar to 1 divided by 3, i.e. endlessly repeating, and therefore not precisely representable no matter how many bits you care to involve, in binary).

That rounding is precisely what you absolutely don't want to happen when representing currency. You don't want a cent to randomly appear or disappear and yet that is *exactly what will happen* if you use `double` to store finance info.

Hence, you're asking about how to render 'cents in a double' appropriately but in fact that question cannot possibly be answered - you can't store cents in a double, hence, it is not possible to render it properly.

Instead..

### Use cents-in-int

The easiest way to do currency correctly is to first determine the accepted atomary unit for your currency, and then store *those*, in `long` or `int` as seems appropriate. For euros, that's eurocents. For bitcoin, that's satoshis. For yen, it's just yen. For dollars, its dollarcents. And so on.

$5.45 is best represented as the int value 545. Not as the double value 5.45, because that's not actually a value a double can represent.

### Why do doubles show up as 0.1?

Because `System.out.println` knows that doubles are wonky and that you're highly likely to want to see 0.1 and not 0.09999999999991238 and thus it rounds inherently. That doesn't magically make it possible to use `double` to represent finance amounts.

### I need to divide, or multiply by complex factors

Division for currency is always nasty. Imagine a cost of 100 dollars that needs to be paid by each 'partner' in a coop. The coop has 120 shares, and each partner has 40 shares, so each partner must pay precisely 1/3 of the cost.

Now what? 100 dollars does not neatly divide into threes. You can't very well charge everybody 33 dollars, 33 cents, and a third of a cent. You could charge everybody 33.33, but now the bank needs to eat 1 cent. You could also charge everybody 33.34, and the bank gets to keep the 2 cents. Or, you could get a little creative, and roll some dice to determine 'the loser'. The loser pays 33.34, the other 2 pay 33.33.

The point is: There is no inherently correct answer. Each situation has its own answer. Hence, division in general is **impossible** without first answering that question. There is no solving this problem unless you have code that knows how to apply the chosen 'division' algorithm. `a / b` cannot be used in any case (as the operation has at least 3 params: The dividend, the divisor, and the algorithm to apply to it).

For foreign exchange, 'multiply by this large decimal value' comes up a lot. You can store arbitrary precision values exactly using the `java.math.BigDecimal` class. However, this is not particularly suitable for storing currencies (all multiplication-by-a-factor will mean the BDs grow ever larger, they still can't divide e.g. 1 by 3 (anything that has repeating digits), and they don't solve the more fundamental issue: Any talk with other systems, such as a bank, can't deal with fractions of atomary units). Stick with BD-space math (as that is perfect, though, can throw exceptions if you divide, and grows ever slower and more complicated over time), until the system you are programming for enforces a rounding to atomary units, at which point, you round, resetting the growth. If you never need to multiply by fractions this doesn't come up, and there's no need to use BigDecimal for anything currency related.

### How do I format cents-in-a-long?

```
String.format("€%d.%02d", cents / 100, cents % 100);
```

It gets very slightly more complicated for negative numbers (% returns negative values, so you need to do something about this. `Math.abs` can help), but not very.
`cents / 100` gives you the "whole" part when you integer-divide by 100, and `% 100` gives you the remainder, which precisely boils down to 'euros' and 'eurocents'.

Comment: Wow. Amazing explaination. To save and reread when I need it!